# Set single constant buffer to multiple locations

Tags: opengl, directx

Can I set single constant buffer to multiple locations in D3D11 and OpenGL? What advantages does this approach have? Do I really need this? Can you think of cases where you would use it?

Dreamed example for D3D11:

```
ID3D11Buffer* bufs[3] = { pBuffer1, pBuffer1, pBuffer1 };
dc->PSSetConstantBuffers(0, 3, &bufs[0]);
```

And OpenGL:

```
glBindBufferBase(GL_UNIFORM_BUFFER, 0, buffer1);
glBindBufferBase(GL_UNIFORM_BUFFER, 1, buffer1);
glBindBufferBase(GL_UNIFORM_BUFFER, 2, buffer1);
```

Comment: I don't know exactly what you are asking, but this may be because I don't know what problem this is trying to solve. If it's not just me, try updating the question with more info and perhaps links to articles. That aside, I see no reason why this would not be allowed, and I also see no reason why this would be useful.

Comment: Might be useful if you do two-sided rendering and you specify separate materials for front and back side (in two separate buffers). Then you could set the same material for front/back side by setting the same buffer.

Comment: ok, fair enough, use case found :-)
Anyone know if its allowed?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, OpenGL does not forbid using the same buffer for different uniform block indices. It also does not forbid binding the same texture to multiple texture image units. And similar such things.

For UBOs, this would be genuinely useful in several cases:

1. Binding different regions of the same buffer. Or to put it another way, storing multiple kinds of data in different regions of the same buffer object.
2. If different shader stages use different buffer binding points, but the client code wants to give them the same data for a particular rendering operation.

But if you're binding the same region of the same buffer to be used by the same shader stage... there's not much genuinely useful you can do with that. You will simply have two uniform blocks in that stage which are copies of the same data.